# Pointer declaration with and without struct?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

What's the difference between:

```
  struct name{
    int example;
    name *next;
    };
```

`struct name *next= NULL;`

...and

```
name *next=NULL;`
```

(defined after the data structure, when the linked list is still empty)
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the data member with name `next` in the structure

```
struct name
{
    int example;
    name *next;
};
```

and variable with the same name declared after the structure as for example

```
struct name *next = NULL;
```

are two different entities.

The last declaration does not initialize to NULL the data member of any object of the structure. It declares a pointer to an object of the type of the structure.

Now about the difference between the two declarations

```
struct name *next = NULL;
```

and

```
name *next = NULL;
```

In the first one there is used so-called elaborated type name `struct name`. Its advantage compared with the second declaration is that any object, enumerator or a function that declared with the same name `name` hide the declaration of the structure. For example

```
struct name
{
    int example;
    name *next;
};

enum { name, noname };
```

Here enumerator `name` hides data type `struct name` and if you write for example

```
name *next = NULL;
```

then the compiler will issue an error.

But if you will use the elaborated name

```
struct name *next = NULL;
```

then the code compiles successfully because the compiler now knows that `name` in this declaration is `struct name`.

Another important difference.

Consider the following code snippet

```
int main()
{
    struct name
    {
        int example;
        name *next;
    };

    {
        name *next = NULL;
    }
}
```

In this progam the declaration within the inner code block declares a pointer of type of the struture declared in the outer code block.

Now rewrite the program

```
int main()
{
    struct name
    {
        int example;
        name *next;
    };

    {
        struct name *next = NULL;
    }
}
```

In this case the declaration in the inner code block introduces a **new type** 
`struct name` that hides the structure declaration in the outer code block.

Answer (score 2):

> *"What's the difference between ..."*

There's none. The `struct` or `class` keyword is optional in pointer declarations.

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva it would be beneficial for everyone if you had gone ahead and read an introductory C++ tutorial. This is perhaps one of the first things a good guide mentions when explaining classes. There's absolutely no need to ask it (yet another time) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Optional in general when declaring.

Comment: @Puppy did that. it was pretty trivial to find one (namely, first Google hit for "C++ struct keyword optional").